# How to create dynamic DLL library in C++, to substitute legacy Fortran DLL

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, fortran, backwards-compatibility

I have to create a dynamic DLL library in C++, to substitute old DLL library written in Fortran, without changing the host application (so functions and parameters must stay the same).

I have full specification of all Fortran functions in that library, but what tools (compiler) I need to use, and what is the way of coding DLL in this situation (stdcall, cdecl, dllexport etc. - that clues doesn't say much to me, I never created a DLL before).

This is sample Fortran function declaration in legacy DLL:

```
SUBROUTINE SetBoundaries(MaxFlow, MinFlow)
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: SetBoundaries
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: "SetBoundaries" :: SetBoundaries

REAL MaxFlow
REAL MinFlow
```

I tried to compile VC2008 DLL but got error:

> Unhandled error in 'InitAllPublicVars' Run-time error 453: Can't find
>   DLL entry point DLLVersion in SomeLib.DLL

Source of this DLL (defining function named DLLVersion doesn't help):

```
void __stdcall SetBoundaries( float *min , float *max ) {
}
```

Is DLLVersion some special DLL procedure or just lack in my documentation and I should create such function?

I know no details about original Fortran DLL source/compilation process, but there are some extracted informations:

[image: General]
[image: Some options]
[image: Imports]

Comment: Which Fortran compiler was used to build the DLL?  What command line options were used with that compiler?  Which C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: C++ - any, Fortran - I don't have informations. Question updated with some extracted details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. DLL functions should be declared like this:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) SetBoundaries( int min , int max ) {

}
```

Note that parameters are not pointers. I logged function calls and DLL gets valid numbers from the host application when put instead of original Fortran DLL. Compiled with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Nice!  I love these kinds of projects, where you can seamlessly drop something new into something old through a defined interface. Your Fortran DLL which did who knows what, maybe now is replaced by your DLL which talks to a bunch of GPU cores via CUDA, or whatever. Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

The runtime library makes the Fortran DLL look like it was built with the Compaq or Digital Fortran compilers.  By default those compilers used the stdcall calling convention.  For your specific example the two arguments (parameters on the C side) are equivalent to `float *`, subroutines are equivalent to void functions.  You would need to use a C++ compiler that supports stdcall.  How you nominate that the function is exported in the DLL depends on your C++ compiler or personal preference, but some sort of dllexport keyword is typical.

From the point of view of change management, it would be far simpler to write the replacement DLL in Fortran and use something like the Intel Fortran compiler, which, being a descendent of the CVF compiler, has appropriate legacy support.  Changes to the DLL source code can then be made in a progressive fashion.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. So you mean, that if i use C++ compiler with stdcall support, and define function like `void __stdcall SetBoundaries( float*,float* )` then compiled DLL should work with original application? (at function call level of course, not bussiness logic). Any other declarations required in C/C++ file? is main function necessary?

Comment: Question updated, I have a `Can't find DLL entry point DLLVersion` error